Is it okay to say "repeat!" instead of "repeat after me!"
Let's say I am an English teacher and I want the students to say what I will say right after me, say, in a context where I teach them how to pronounce the word "world". I know that "repeat after me" is the set phrase but I'd like to know whether it is okay to say just "repeat" instead. Like:

Repeat! World!

I am guessing it would be okay, but I'd like get the opinion of some native English speakers.

What do you mean by "okay"? You would certainly be understood. "Repeat after me" is the better choice, and you seem to acknowledge that. I think you'll get better answers if you edit to talk more about why you want to use just "repeat" instead, and what kind of "not okay" you're worried about.

@AndyBonner I wonder if it is naturally used by native English speakers. The reason why I would maybe like to use it is because it is less wordy than "repeat after me."

Teachers say: Repeat after me the first time around.

This looks like a silly question to me. The idea that words should be used "sparingly" in speech is illogical, and doesn't reflect how any language works. A sports teacher might need to show pupils how to do something, and thus he might say "Watch me doing it, then copy me". Only a really weird teacher would think of reducing that to just "Copy"

If you want to issue orders such as Repeat! and Copy! you might enjoy using a whip to get the students into class, and wear a military uniform. Nul points.

It would be understood, but sounds harsh/brusque. It is not common usage.

No, simply saying "Repeat" isn't idiomatic and doesn't sound natural to a native speaker. Here are some ways that a native speaker who is a teacher might prompt students to practice pronunciation in this way:

Repeat after me
Say it after me

These both may be used exactly as in your example, such as:

Teacher: Repeat after me. World. gestures at class
Class: World.
Teacher: Earth. gestures
Class: Earth.

It would also be common for a teacher to use any of the following:

Your turn
You try
Try it

However, these would come after the example, such as the following:

Teacher: World. Now your turn.
Class: World.
Teacher: Earth. Your turn.
Class: Earth.


A command to "repeat" is idiomatic, but it means to do whatever you just did again; it would not typically mean to speak aloud the words that follow. It would be completely natural for an instructor to say, "Repeat after me - 'world'. Repeat. Repeat. Repeat," which would have the students say 'world' 4 times. A command to "repeat" is not necessarily synonymous with the command "repeat after me", but it is idiomatic in the appropriate context.

@NuclearHoagie Thank you both. I don't exactly understand what you mean, Nuclear. Do you say it is okay or not in my case to just say "Repeat!"?

@FireandIce It would be OK as a subsequent instruction when the context is already clear what should be repeated (usually whatever was just said/done). But I would not rely on it to convey the idea that one should repeat what I'm about to say - "repeat after me" accomplishes that much more naturally.

If you're telling a class to repeat something, you want them to do something quite specific: not just to say the word any old how, but to say it in the way you say it, and the phrase "after me" suggests that: one meaning of "after" is "in accordance with" or "in the characteristic manner of".
